# Understanding salt environments

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to know what is the utility of declaring environments in /etc/salt/master ?

Example :

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
  env1:
    - /srv/salt/env1
```

This is the /srv/salt tree:

```
.
├── base
├── env1
│   └── domain1
│       ├── init.sls
│       └── nginx.conf
└── top.sls
```

And the top.sls:

```
env1:
  '*':
    - env1.domain1
```

This is the init.sls inside env1/domain1/

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
  file.managed:
      - source: salt://env1/domain1/nginx.conf
```

When executing:

```
salt '*' state.sls env1.domain1
```

everything works fine.

But with highstate:

```
# salt '*' state.highstate
myHost:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'env1.domain1' in env 'env1'
```

Given that the environment "env1" is declared in master config.I changed my configuration and I have put :

```
- source: salt://domain1/nginx.conf
```

instead of:

```
- source: salt://env1/domain1/nginx.conf
```

I had this error :

```
 Comment: Source file salt://domain1/nginx.conf not found
```

Is there a misconfiguration somewhere ?
What is the utility of declaring environments in master conf, 
if we can't call it directly using `salt://subfolder` instead of `salt://environment/subfolder` directly ?

I can't find a good documentation about creating environments and using them !

**===Edit===**

This is the new configuration:

**The master:**

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/base
  env1:
    - /srv/salt/env1
```

**The /srv/salt tree**

```
.
├── base
│   └── init.sls
├── conf_template
├── env1
│   └── domain1
│       ├── init.sls
│       └── nginx.conf
└── top.sls
```

**top.sls:**

```
base:
  '*':
    - init
env1:
  '*':
    - domain1
```

**And env1/domain1/init.sls:**

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
  file.managed:
      - source: salt://domain1/nginx.conf
```

**and the execution result:**

```
salt '*' state.sls env1.domain1
myHost:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'env1.domain1' in env 'base'
```

Comment: This github issue (comment dialog )helped me solve this issue: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/10447

Answer (score 1):

> No matching sls found for 'env1.domain1' in env 'env1'

I believe that's because the state reference should not include the environment, i.e. you have an extra `env1`, it should be:

```
env1:
  '*':
    - domain1
```

The other mistake you have is that you have `env1` as a sub-directoy of `base` which can make things really confusing as this is not how environments are supposed to be structured.

Those are the only two mistakes I can spot and after fixing them, highstate should work as well as the reference to `salt://domain1/nginx.conf` (which is correct this way).

Finally, I believe environments are indeed confusing, and for me, I found I could better understand them by focusing on how they are actually implemented: *multiple state trees*. Technically, the concept of an "environment" doesn't exist. It's just one for us to utilize that feature.

Comment: Thank you. I made what you've recommended. Could you please take a look at the update ?